# Dynamically pass in values in Python files

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk

I have two Python files. One file is dealing with the AWS CDK and creates a DynamoDB table resource. The second file is is executing a function where it is putting items into the table and is outside of the CDK package. Currently I have the table name hardcoded in the put item method. I would like to get to state where the table name is being read in from the CDK. Python newbie here, so any advice would be appreciated. Below is the code I have prepared so far:

**First Python File**

```
from aws_cdk import (
core as cdk,
aws_dynamodb as dynamodb
)
from aws_cdk import core


class CdkStack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        currentDate= date.today()
        table_name= 'DynamoTableToPassInOtherFile'
        dynamodbTable= dynamodb.Table(self,id='dynamodbTable',table_name=table_name,partition_key=dynamodb.Attribute(name='id',type=dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING))
```

**Second Python File**

```
def write_to_dynamo_db(self, json):
    dynamodb_response = dynamodb_client.put_item(
                TableName= "DynamoTableToReadFromOtherFile",
                Item={
                    'id':{'S': self.id},
                    'formatted_date': {'S': json},
                    },
                ReturnValues='ALL_OLD',
                ReturnConsumedCapacity='INDEXES',
            )
    return dynamodb_response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# you can import CdkStack from file1 into file 2 like this
from file1 import CdkStack

def write_to_dynamo_db(self, cdkStack, json):
    dynamodb_response = dynamodb_client.put_item(
                TableName= cdkStack.table_name,
                Item={
                    'id':{'S': self.id},
                    'formatted_date': {'S': json},
                    },
                ReturnValues='ALL_OLD',
                ReturnConsumedCapacity='INDEXES',
            )
    return dynamodb_response


# then create an instance of CdkStack (if not already created, otherwise you can import the instance) and pass it to your method (or just pass the table_name attribute from that instance).
cdkStack = CdkStack()
something.write_to_dynamo_db(cdkStack=cdkStack, json=json)
```

Not sure what the rest of your code in file2 looks like, but this is the general pattern you could use.

For more info:

[Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: So the file1 I have is in a subdirectory for the CDK. I'm assuming I need to move that CDK python file into the same directory as the file2 if I'm importing.

Comment: After importing File1 in File2 and executing File2, I am getting "ModuleNotFoundError" about the libraries being used in File1. Any ideas how to get those packages imported in this case?

Comment: You should create a "\_\_init\_\_.py" file in the directory that contains file1.  File1 does not need to be in the same directory as file2.  You can specify the path in your import statement.  For example, "from dir1.dir2.dir3.file1 import CdkStack".

Comment: After integrating the import from file1, I'm getting a ModuleNotFoundError stating there is no module 'cdk' installed. I have the cdk installed in the virtual environment when executing the CdkStack function. I'm unable to install it outside of the virtual environment for cdk.